# Good practice to NEVER allow clipping or...?

Tags: modeling

I heard that in a VFX studio, they would make sure that all objects do not ever intersect with one another? But in some tutorials I see (modelling a gun, for example), they do SOME overlapping/clipping objects into another?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is only one person's opinion, but I think for the most part (depending on use case), overlapping of objects is ok, so long as no faces occupy the same space at the same angle at the same time. For example, a face can intersect  another face at 90 degrees without problems, but if there angles are the same and they are "flush" with each other, they will cause Z-fighting.

Comment: @samk At the moment your question is unclear to me. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter I'm hearing from someone that I should not allow the kind of clipping that the pics show. In VFX studios, they do "contact pass," and I heard that if they saw something like that, they would send it back to you. I'm trying to find out if that is good practice. I heard clipping creates weird shadows, but I haven't encountered it, nor don't know what that means.

Comment: in your example it doesn't seem like we are able to see the potentially overlaping faces, in that case it should not matter, the problem is when you see overlapping faces, it creates bad artefacts, is it what you meant?